# Como mover o box do input

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Eu gostaria de apenas mover o box (a caixinha em sí) do input para a direita da minha div.

```
    <div id='mainBox'>
Distancia departure/arrival <input class='inputs'>
<p></p>
Distancia arrival/alternate <input class='inputs'>
<p></p>
Velocidade de cruzeiro <input class='inputs'>
<p></p>
Consumo da aeronave em litros <input class='inputs'>

</div>
```

[image: Gostaria de jogar os campos de inserção de dados para a direita dessa box!]

Ja tentei de tudo que é jeito, através de margin e padding, mas as inputs ficam todas desordenadas :/

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja correta, não esqueça de avaliar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O que entendi o que você quer é mover o input para a direita, se for isto, o seguinte trecho irá resolver:

```
#mainBox input{
 float:right;
}
```

Galera a resposta está correta, deram down vote desnecessário aqui.

Comment: Você pode dar um margin-right em "px" também caso não queira que fique totalmente a direita.

Comment: Valeu! Era justamente isso! Aprendi mais uma :)

Comment: lol não entendi os downvotes '-'

Comment: Pois é, deram downvotes desnecessário aqui :(

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução possível:

- Dê os rótulos display: inline-block
- Dê-lhes uma largura fixa
- Alinhar o texto à direita

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}​
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <label>Primeira Label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label>Segunda Label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label>Terceira Label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu cara! Era bem isso!

Comment: @LisandroBeltrã, se a solução está correta, não esqueça de avaliar.